# Bundle ID Suffix? What is it?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect, ios

I'm new to the iPhone submission process. Apple asks for the Bundle ID Suffix. What is this? Not sure what to put here and what the significance of it is.

Answer (score 71):

If you don't have a company, leave your name, it doesn't matter as long as both bundle id in info.plist file and the one you've submitted in iTunes Connect match.

In Bundle ID Suffix you should write full name of bundle ID.

Example:

```
Bundle ID suffix = thebestapp (NOT CORRECT!!!!)

Bundle ID suffix = com.awesomeapps.thebestapp (CORRECT!!)
```

The reason for this is explained in the [Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle):

> The App ID string contains two parts separated by a period (.) — an **App ID Prefix** (your Team ID by default, e.g. `ABCDE12345`), and an **App ID Suffix** (a Bundle ID search string, e.g. `com.mycompany.appname`). [emphasis added]

So in this case the suffix is the full string `com.awesomeapps.thebestapp`.

Comment: But what makes one way correct, and the other not correct?  Will bad things happen if you have forgotten to use the longer name?

Comment: do you have to put the `com.company.app` as opposed to `company.app` in your info plist?

Comment: Doesn't matter the order and format as long as it matches your Provisioning Profile.

Comment: what if the app's name is `TheBestApp`, then does the suffix need to be `com.mycompanyname.TheBestApp`?

Answer (score 31):

The bundle identifier is an ID for your application used by the system as a domain for which it can store settings and reference your application uniquely.

It is represented in reverse DNS notation and it is recommended that you use your company name and application name to create it.

An example bundle ID for an App called The Best App by a company called Awesome Apps would look like:

```
com.awesomeapps.thebestapp
```

In this case the suffix is `thebestapp`.

Comment: Thanks!

When submitting, it gives me a dropdown for the Bundle ID. In my case it says: nameofapp - *. If I set the bundle ID suffix is ABC, what would I set the bundle id in the info.plist to?

Comment: I explained that in my answer. It should be `com.companyname.ABC`

Comment: i'm confused about App ID, if my App ID is A123B45C9D.* what i have to write when i fill the bundle ID field?

Comment: App IDs are completely separate from bundle IDs. App IDs are the ID of your app in the app store, where the bundle ID is used by iOS to uniquely identify your application. Please read my answer. The bundle ID should follow reverse DNS format: com.something.somethingelse

Comment: Just to be clear, if my companies domain name ends in .gov should my bundle id be: gov.awesomeapps.thebestapp?

Comment: Can I use four segments? e.g. com.awesomeapps.gamesdivision.thebestgame

Comment: none of the comments here really nail it, in terms of understanding why. The request is for a SUFFIX, as opposed to a PREFIX. The bundle name is thebestapp, so the suffix com.awesomeapps end up in front. That's not a suffix. Since Apple asks for an App name in one of the input fields beforehand, that forms the bundle INFIX. That part of it is supplied. No wonder the OP is confused. The answer? - Just put anything, see what results and edit before submission, just make sure you "tell the same lies" everywhere

Comment: what if my website domain is awesomeapps.co.uk?