# Bundle ID and App Submission

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bundle ID Suffix? What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436260/bundle-id-suffix-what-is-it)

The answers on here for this issue do not quite cover my question.

From info.plist

```
Bundle Identifier : art.capeann.mobile.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
Bundle Name : ${PRODUCT_NAME}
```

In iTunes connect, what do I enter for Bundle ID Suffix

```
Bundle ID Suffix = [what do I put here?]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Bundle ID Suffix you should write the full name of the bundle ID.

This is what not to do
Example: Bundle ID suffix = thebestapp

This is what to do
Bundle ID = com.awesomeapps.thebestapp

Comment: Where thebestapp would be the sufix

Comment: This is the first time publishing for me.  This is the Identifier in plist... "art.capeann.mobile.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}"  What exactly will I type into Bundle ID Suffix in iTunes connect?

Comment: You must put your app name in Bundle ID Sufix "mobile". The Bundle ID however is meant to be in reverse domain format like com.companyName.yourAppName