# How to create a new app id in the iOS provisioning portal?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

**Context**

- I'm trying to upload a lite version of a "full" app, (this full app is already in the store).
- I created this lite version using the multiple target approach (basically the same Xcode project with a different pList file)
- I've been able to create ad-hoc builds and publish to my device for this lite version.

**Problem**

I'm getting the "No Identities are available for signing" issue, when I try and push the lite version to the store.

**What I think is the solution**

I think I need to create a new provisioning profile, as for the ad-hoc builds I think I was using a wildcard provisioning profile, but I don't think I can use that for the app store.

The lite version has a different app bundle id, which I think is causing the issue. How to I go about creating a distribution profile for this new bundle ID?

[image]

Comment: You have to get it approved by Apple, just like the full version.

Comment: The app id? How to I submit it for approval?

Comment: How did you submit the first app for approval?  Every app like this that I've seen has two different versions on the store, a "lite" version and a "full" version.  Sometimes I've seen a "standard" version sold, in which you can do in-app purchases for additional features.

Comment: They're the same thing, AFAIK.  Why would you have two apps using the same App ID?

Comment: The question states: "The lite version has a different app bundle id,"

Comment: You're out of my level of expertise now.  I don't know what an app bundle ID is.  It sounds like a way to do in-app purchases, not a backdoor for adding new application flavors.

Comment: OK, I did a [little reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3436664/102937), and I think you're confusing App ID with App Bundle ID.  I stand by my original assertion: `App ID == App`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ignore for a moment that this is a lite version of an existing app. Treat this the way it is - it is a completely new app. Therefore you must go through the entire process again.

In the provisioning portal you need to create a new App Id with the proper settings. Then you need to create a distribution provisioning profile with the new app id. Then install that profile into Xcode. Then setup your app to use that provisioning profile. Then you should be able to archive the app. You also need to add the new app as a completely new app in iTunes Connect and make it ready for upload. Then you can finally submit the app.

Comment: Thanks rmdaddy, but where to I create the App ID in the provisioning portal? I don't see an option for it.

Comment: In the screenshot you posted, you first need to go to the Identifiers section on the left and create a new App ID. Then you go to the Provisioning Profile section.

Comment: Just to confirm, I just submitted the app. Thank rmaddy you saved me.