# iTunes Connect - There was an error creating your Bundle ID

Tags: ios, submit, bundle, app-store-connect

I'm trying to set up my first app in iTunes Connect so I can submit it... and I go through the whole set up process of entering metadata, and when I go to save on the last screen I get this error:

> There was an error creating your Bundle ID.

[image]

And it won't let me save it.  To clarify, I'm not even to the point that my app can be submitted, this is the app setup before you submit.

I'm not understanding what's going on here.  I created the certificates, bundle IDs and provisioning profiles correctly, and the bundle ID I'm using shows in the bundle ID dropdown on the first page, etc etc.  As far as I can see nothing is wrong, yet it won't let me create the app.

I already went through, deleted my previous bundle IDs and all that, recreated them, and still it gives me this error.  I searched around and couldn't find any information on this.  Anyone have an idea why this might occur?

Comment: can't really tell as we don't know the current config.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  Are you using a wildcard app id?

Comment: @Mike M Yeah I was.  I tried it again a while later, using a new App ID that didn't have a wildcard, and it went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. You can register the new App ID from your developer portal - Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles module. Then create your app in iTunes Connect again with selecting existing app ID you just created. Good luck.

Comment: This is what I did a while later... created a new one without a wildcard, and it worked.  So either the wildcard was causing a problem, or maybe too busy as @Lim Thye Chean suggested below... don't know which, but I'm good now.  Thanks.

Comment: TRy: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/115.0 or https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436260/bundle-id-suffix-what-is-it and https://itunesconnect.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

> 1.The Bundle Identifier should be same with the Bundle ID when you create your app in iTunes Connect. Just enter a bundle identifier in
> plist and copy the same in App ID section of itunes connect.
>
> 2.Your Bundle Seed ID (App ID Prefix) ie. 10 digit code SHOULD NOT be entered into xcode nor the bundle ID when creating your app above. The
> only place you will see it is the App ID within PROVISIONING PORTAL >
> App IDs. This was very confusing - basically just enter the above
> (com.companyname.appname) for App ID SUFFIX

Comment: That's the thing, I'm trying to create the app in iTunes Connect so I can submit it after.  I haven't gotten to the part when I actually submit.  My Bundle ID is com.MYNAME.*  In the setup I'm choosing that from the dropdown, then I add my suffix so it's com.MYNAME.SUFFIX.  Then when I finish adding all my metadata and go to save, it gives me that error and won't let me continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a timing issue. Probably iTunes Connect too busy. I have been registering apps these few days and all gone fine - and just got it an hour ago! I would suggest give it a try later, and tell us if it works!

PS: I waited for an hour, and tried again for the 3rd time, and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I also found another "solution". If my default language is non-English (I tested Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese), the creation of bundle ID will fail. But if it is English, it will work!

So all I need to do create the app in English, then later switch to non-English.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround is to re-add a development center in the App ID (as you use wildcards on the line), and then select the iTunes Connect App ID that you just created on it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new AppID and removing the "com.yourcompany" from the name solved it for me.